# What do I do when pg_cancel_backend doesn't work?

Tags: database, sql, postgresql

If I have a long-running Postgres query, and regular "kill [pid]" doesn't work, and pg_cancel_backend doesn't work, what should I do?

Answer (score 13):

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/server-shutdown.html

pg_cancel_backend is equivalent to sending SIGINT to the process.
pg_terminate_backend likewise for SIGTERM, but if pg_cancel_backend isn't working I don't see why pg_terminate_backend would.

If you've tried those options, you could try SIGQUIT.  The docs say, "**This is recommended only in emergencies.**"

(If you hate your data and hope it dies, you could use SIGKILL.  But I wouldn't.)

You can use either `kill` directly or `pg_ctl kill`.

Comment: +1 PostgreSQL uses a process per connection, so you can kill a process without much danger of affecting other connections. I'm not sure if there's any chance of data corruption, but I'd really doubt it.

Comment: I thought sending kill -9 to a postgres process was disastrous, in that it could put the database in recovery mode which might take it out of commission for many minutes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920956/how-do-i-gracefully-kill-stale-server-process-postgres

It seems I am wrong.

Comment: That link regards sending kill -9 to the *server*. I'm talking about a single query's pid. Or are those the same thing?

Comment: Each connection spawns off a `postmaster`.  You can send your signals to the postmaster, but don't send a SIGKILL (killall postmaster) as this will drop whatever it was doing like a hot rock.

Comment: Clearly someone more knowledgeable than me should answer this question.

Comment: @Bribles **please add a warning to your post! SIGQUIT will cause SERIOUS ISSUES if tried. I just did and it caused a whole lot of problems - I wish I could go back in time and stop myself from hitting that Enter key!**

Comment: @ADTC Warning added.  And a link to the docs, which is probably the best edit I could've made.

Answer (score 9):

You should **never** kill -9 any postgres process unless your goal is to bring the entire server down forcibly.  You can kill any process that doesn't respond to a pg_cancel_backend() call from the shell with

```
kill <pid>
```

i.e. not -9.  Note that I have seen a few times where even that didn't work due to the process being hung waiting in some loop for data on a network connection.  If I recall correctly, killing the client process took care of that.

Answer (score 6):

if you have a recent Postgres you can try `pg_terminate_backend` instead.

Answer (score 1):

[bribles](https://serverfault.com/users/4188/bribles) is correct in his statement above...

*IF* you are trying to `SHUTDOWN` the server, for me though:

I'm just trying to remove retired Databases/Schemas,
that still have a lingering connection that it won't let go of.

So, to answer your question,

> If I have a long-running Postgres query ...
>
> pg_cancel_backend doesn't work...
>
> what should I do?

**NOT RELATED** to shutting down the server in any way.

I have also seen this behavior of `pg_cancel_backend()` not working.
And wanted to share my working solution.

I have not seen an issue thus far, with any kind of "loss" of data.

Again, I'm not trying to kill `Active` queries either.

> -- I'm logged into as USER "A"  with a session or PID of 777777.
>
> -- And going to try and force disconnect another session from USER "A" open as 123456789
>
> -- Which is a sleeping connection, and is why I also look for `idle` in my queries below.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM pg_stat_activity 
WHERE pid = 123456789 
      AND STATE = 'idle';
```

> -- Attempt 1

```sql
SELECT pg_cancel_backend(pid) 
FROM pg_stat_activity 
WHERE pid = 123456789 
      AND STATE = 'idle';
```

> -- Interestingly enough Result states that the cancellation is TRUE but still exists.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM pg_stat_activity 
WHERE pid = 123456789 
      AND STATE = 'idle';
```

> -- Attempt 2

```sql
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid) 
FROM pg_stat_activity 
WHERE pid = 123456789 
      AND STATE = 'idle';
```

> -- And Now it doesn't exist..

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM pg_stat_activity 
WHERE pid = 123456789 
      AND STATE = 'idle';
```

> -- NOTE: I tried to use ridiculous pid #'s to help prevent people from copying & pasting and wrecking their lives.
>
> -- NOTE: By default postgres will ONLY allow you to kill processes running under YOUR logging in USER,
>
> -- NOTE: but you knew that already.

Hope this helps. =)

~Jay